# What is the difference between making a cheesecake with confectioner's sugar vs. normal sugar?

Tags: baking, cake, sugar, cheesecake

I would like to make a cheesecake with [confectioner's sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powdered_sugar) and though it's been awhile since I've made cheesecake, I believe I used normal sugar before. However, I only have confectioner's sugar on hand at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this, and it was regrettable. The flavor of the cheesecake was acceptable (not great though), but the texture left something to be desired.

Like Dorothy pointed out, there is cornstarch in confectioner's sugar. This left the cheesecake I ended up with incredibly dense, and it also cracked (more than usual) while baking.

I *would not* recommend using confectioner's sugar as a substitute for granulated sugar when baking a cheesecake based on my experience. I certainly would not try it again. At least, not without taking the time to do something to offset the cornstarch effect. Adding a liquid could do the trick, but right now I would be guessing on what and how much to use.

It's easier to just head to the market for what you need in this case.

Comment: You assume all readers know that *powdered sugar* is the same as *confectioner's sugar*. They don't - this is an international site.

Answer (score 7):

While you could use it, it would likely affect the finished product. As a substitute in baking, when the recipe calls for granulated sugar, powdered sugar is not always suitable. And, although it is granulated sugar which has been processed into powder, cornstarch has also been added to prevent clumping.

With sugar, the size of a granule determines how well air incorporates into the batter. The larger the granule, the more air and, since the batter needs that air to help it rise, using powdered sugar will not produce the same results.

Comment: +1 for mentioning granule size as well. If you don't mix the batter until all sugar has been dissolved, this makes a difference in the end result.

Answer (score 0):

granulated sugar will add some aeration by cutting into the fat of the cream cheese. icing sugar will just dissolve and blend in. it's mostly a texture difference rather than a flavor difference. use granulated.

Answer (score -1):

Regular white sugar will make the taste richer, with more flavor than powdered sugar.

Comment: Can you explain why two grain sizes of sugar - that both should dissolve in the wet cheesecake filling - give a different taste?

Comment: Given that powdered sugar has additives, it will be less sweet per gram actually :)